# Windows Azure Static content website / Azure Blob storage - outbound Data transfers Price comparison

Tags: azure, bandwidth, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service, static-site

I have some scripts and images(total size is 1MB) in the web role.  I am planning to move these to some blob storage(CDN/Https/Query string) or static website.

The price for outbound data transfers (i.e. data going out of Windows Azure data centers)

First 10 TB / Month*    $.12 per GB
source (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-11)

I would like to know If I move the scripts and images to the following

1.Static content website (or) 
2. Blob storage(Https)

Are the Price for outbound transfers same?  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Microsoft site.

> All inbound data sent to Windows Azure is free. Outbound data is
> charged based on the total amount of data moving out of the Windows
> Azure data centers via the Internet in a given billing cycle. Data
> transfers between Windows Azure services located within the same data
> center are not subject to any charge. The first 5 GB of outbound data
> transfers per billing month are also free.
>
> Full details http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-11

They don't mention details about specific services as they only monitor outbound transters for billing according to that information.

**EDIT**

One thing to bear in mind using blob storage you are limited to the number of accesses per second (I think this is 500) so a heavily loaded site will need to use the CDN as well as just blob storage.

Comment: Both are different services. I was assuming that Charges for outbound datatransfer should be much cheaper in Azure blob storage comparing to Azure static website.

Comment: The per-byte charge is the same, but the bandwidth is different.  A single core VM (WebRole or VM) will get 100Mb/sec.  Egress from storage is 5Gb/sec.  For a heavily loaded site, you will get much better perf for the same price by moving content to blobs.

Comment: Yes as @Pat Filoeo said you will get better performance but don't forget the request limit per second when you reach that you need the cdn in place as that doesn't have the same restrictions as blob storage as it's just a proxy essentially.